# InstallShield (InstallScript Project): Uninstall files at update - How can I prevent this?

Tags: installshield, installscript

I'm quite new in the InstallShield stuff, I took this project from a leaving co-worker. However, here's my problem:

I was trying to update a MySQL Server with the setup from 5.7.17 to 5.7.19, which works great most of the times. 
I got the feature "*MySQL*", splitted in "*MySQL Data*" (includes the performance_schema and mysql database), "*MySQL Service*" (Service batch files) and "*MySQL Binaries*" (the files).

For the update, I just changed the binaries by the new one and left the rest. **All features are selected** and my log tells me, that it installs all files which it hasn't installed by now, leaving the existing files untouched. As this is an update, it seems correct to me.

But sometimes, at the end of the setup process, **it uninstalls almost anything of my MySQL Feature again**; the databases, the batch files and almost any core file which wasn't changed by the setup before. But why is that and how can I stop my setup from do so?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're describing is that your file containing the data is not getting updated. Since this type of file cannot be versioned, that's what Windows installer uses to determine whether or not to upgrade the file, you will need to mark the component containing this file to Always Overwrite. Check out the MS docs for the [Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx) table for how to do this with the Attributes field.

Comment: It's true that the Components are currently on "Never". However, Always is a possible value for the MySQL source files, but not suitable for the performance_schema table, which is inserted by this setup as well, but may change ofc... Thanks for that clue anyway, I will try this out for the suitable mysql-contents

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check the conditions on the components in question. Also, check the install sequence to see if it is calling uninstall out of sequence.

Comment: If his install is authored using best practices then the install sequence should not change. If the data file is in a component than it's probably not overwriting it.

Comment: Your comments contain a lot of IF statements (assumptions) to rate answer negatively.  It is true that unversioned files could display erratic behavior but question seems to state that install leaves the files untouched and then uninstalls them at the end SOMETIMES.

Comment: I doubt that this is the problem. I checked my script code and haven't found anything which deselects features after the installation has started. And, as some parts of them are installed, it must be selected.